# Graphics 2D not drawing images in Java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm following a Java course, and the current idea is to draw an image using Java Graphics2D. I'm following the steps one by one, but it seems not to be drawing anything. The panel is shown within the frame and everything is correct, but the image is not drawn. I'm using Java 15 and the course is Java 13.

JPanel class code:

```java
public class MyPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    Image ball;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    MyPanel(){
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(PANEL_WIDTH,PANEL_HEIGHT));
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        ball = new ImageIcon("ball.png").getImage();
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D G2D = (Graphics2D) g;
        G2D.drawImage(ball,x,y,null);}
```

JFrame class code:

```java
public class MyFrame extends JFrame{
    MyPanel panel;

    MyFrame(){
        panel = new MyPanel();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.add(panel);
        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Main class code:

```java
new MyFrame();
```

I picked out most of the relevant code.

Comment: Are you sure that "ball.png" is correctly loaded? Try to check if ball is null.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java graphics2D inside JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43843811/java-graphics2d-inside-jpanel)

Comment: The "ball.png" is correctly loaded and contained in the project folder, so I don't need the absolute path, and the ball isn't null so I donnu.
Yeah and that website didn't help me, bcz first it's using another way and the second that it's about drawing rectangles, and rectangles worked with me.
Thank you for your effort so much.

Comment: `new ImageIcon("ball.png")` references a file on the file system, which MUST be at the same location the code is executed

Comment: It is actually in the project folder, it's in the same location, but it didn't work

Comment: @MajdHajHmedy The "project folder" may not be the "execution" location, just beware

Comment: The `paint` method in `MyPanel` is never called because you do not overwrite the method with `@Override`. I would also recommend using `paintComponent` instead of `paint`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I recommend reading through [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) to get a better idea of how painting in Swing should work.

I then suggest reading through [Reading/Loading an Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)

The "problem" with `ImageIcon` is that

1. It doesn't report any errors if the load fails
2. It loads the image in a second thread, which means you don't know (easily) when it's available

`ImageIO` on the hand will throw an error if the image can't be loaded, which is much easier to diagnose, and will only return AFTER the image is fully loaded and available.

One concept which can be hard to grasp when your starting is the concept of "embedded" resources.  Java allows you to package "resources" along with your code.  These resources live within the context of your programs class path and make it MUCH easier to load when compared to having to deal with external files.

Have a look [Packaging and accessing run-time resources in a runnable Jar](https://www.cefns.nau.edu/%7Eedo/Classes/CS477_WWW/Docs/pack_resources_in_jar.html) for some basics.

Depending on the IDE you're using, it's usually pretty easy to "copy" these resources into your project/src and allow the IDE to package itself.

The problem with a question like this is it's very, very hard for anyone to truely diagnose, as there are so many reasons why the image might not have loaded and the solution is usual one of trial and error.

Me, I'd start by just drawing some lines/rectangles and make sure that `paint` is been called.  I'd then look at things like the image's size, to make sure it's not something like `0x0`.

## Runnable example

This is a simple runnable example based on comments I made above.  I'm using NetBeans and the image was stored in the "Source Package" (so, along with the other source code) under the `/images` package

[image: Beach Ball]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage beachBall;

        public TestPane() {
            try {
                beachBall = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/BeachBall.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (beachBall == null) {
                return;
            }
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int x = (getWidth() - beachBall.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - beachBall.getHeight()) / 2;
            g2d.drawImage(beachBall, x, y, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It really looks like your image is not loaded.
As @MadProgrammer just told, `new ImageIcon("ball.png")` does not raise any error, and `getImage()` will always return something (not `null`), even if the file is not properly loaded.

To make sure your image is available, you can try `ball.getWidth(null)`, and
if it returns `-1`, then something went wrong.
You can check the root path used by the JVM ("execution" location) with `System.getProperty("user.dir")`, the image file has to be exactly in this folder.

I tried your code with java 1.8 and it works well.

Comment: Thank you so MUCH! it turned out that the image is in the project folder but not in the root of it-somewhere in the out folder-, and that's because I dragged it and dropped into the project in the IDE.